# NHibernate - is there any point in setting length attribute for properties/columns?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

typically definition of property/column looks like this:

```
<property name="DocumentSummary" column="DocumentSummary" length="100" type="String">
   <column name="DocumentSummary" />
</property>
```

I was assuming that NHibernate will validate data using length attribute before inserting/updating a row. Unfortunately it seems to be invalid assumption. So question is if NHibernate is using length attribute for anything? Does it make sense to set it for each property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It using it to create database definition sql. Look at SchemaExport class.

Answer (score 1):

Also you might be able to programmically pull the lengths from the mappings, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516906/getting-column-length-from-hibernate-mappings) question. Note that that is for Java Hibernate, but I believe you might be able to translate that to NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting the `Length` property makes a different where you have string columns with a length that exceeds the default maximum length.

We have a column of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. If we didn't set the `length` property, NHibernate would fail to set the string value if the value had a length greater than 4096 characters.

(This example uses Mapping-By-Code, because we're in 2017 :-)

```
classMapper.Property(
                        tickerFeed => tickerFeed.StaticTickerText,
                        propertyMapper =>
                        {
                             propertyMapper.Column("StaticTickerText");
                             propertyMapper.Length(int.MaxValue);
                        }
                    );
```

However, we found we could achieve the same result using `IPropertyMapper.Type` to stipulate that it was a large string.

```
classMapper.Property(
                        tickerFeed => tickerFeed.StaticTickerText,
                        propertyMapper =>
                        {
                             propertyMapper.Column("StaticTickerText");
                             propertyMapper.Type(NHibernateUtil.StringClob);
                        }
                    );
```

We ended up going with the `propertyMapper.Type` option, as it is more explicit.