# How Do I Retrieve The Class Name From Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, classname

If there's already a question that addresses this, then could I please get a link as I cannot find one.

I'm looking to obtain the stored class name of an object stored in my Hibernate database. When I look at the database externally I see the strings stored that have the classname. How can I retrieve the class name without constructing the object?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** No I am not specifically specifying the discriminator; these are in fact subclasses being stored. I'm simply trying to get the actual subclass of the object.

Comment: As far as I know Hibernate doesn't store he class name in the database, right?  It gets the mapping from either the xml configuration files or annotated classes.

Comment: It sort of does. I have pgAdmin open and I can see a resemblance of the class name in one of the database columns. It's not the exact class name, but it would suffice for my purposes.

Comment: The only way I can think of that you would see the class name in the database is if you're using a subclass and not explicitly defining the discriminator value.  Hibernate will use the class name as the discriminator in that case.  I'd suggest you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what's happening, I am not explicitly defining the discriminator value.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, depending on how your instances are mapped into the database format. In both cases, the first step is to get hold of the `Configuration` instance of Hibernate which contains the mapping config (see [the API docs](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/package-frame.html)).

The root object is `Configuration`, the information you seek is probably returned by `getTableMappings()`. You'll have to use a debugger and the Hibernate source and some time to figure out how everything works.

If you're using Spring, you'll have to figure a way to get at the Configuration object. Your best bet is to set a breakpoint in `Configuration.buildSessionFactory()`. That should give you an idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516906 - that answer shows you how to loop through all the mappings.  PersistentClass.getTable will get you the table name so if you're starting with the table you should be able to loop through all the class mappings until you find the one you want. Subclasses may confuse the issue since one table can map to multiple classes.

Comment: @Brian: You should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new field in the object that stored its type. This is what I used for my solution, however I'd still like answers as to how to access the discriminator value.